# Returning an array from function in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have these 2 functions

Here I get details from sales table

```
   var getLedgerDetails = function (name, id, res) {
    var response = [];
    var f = '%d %b %Y';
    connection.query("SELECT id,voucher_type,DATE_FORMAT(date,?) as date,amount,voucher_number FROM sales WHERE ledger_name=? and company_id=?", [f, name, id], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        else {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                var r = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
                var row = JSON.parse(r);
                return row[0];
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    })
};
```

and second is

here i want to access the getLedgerDetails Function

```
getDetails=function(name,id,res){

            //**returns undefined**
             console.log(getLedgerDetails(name,id,res)); 
             }
```

but it returns me undefined..It makes the function call but returns no value
where i am wrong??

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: no im working with nodejs not javascript though i already  tried the solution which is there in the link

Comment: you need to understand nature of JavaScript, I mean how to handle asynchronous call(callback, promise, async/await)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your code is asynchronous, you have to return your data in a callback function which will be called only at the end.

You can try something like this :

```
var getLedgerDetails=function(name,id,res, callback) {
        var response = [];
        var f = '%d %b %Y';
        connection.query("SELECT id,voucher_type,DATE_FORMAT(date,?) as date,amount,voucher_number FROM sales WHERE ledger_name=? and company_id=?", [f, name, id], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err, null);
            }
            else {
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    var r = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
                    var row = JSON.parse(r);
                    callback(null, row[0]);
                }
                else {
                    callback(null, null);
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

And your getDetails function

```
getDetails=function(name,id,res){

    getLedgerDetails(name, id, res, function(err, row) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(row);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: see i am calling it like this way console.log("hhh"+getLedgerDetails(name,id,res,function(err, row) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
  }
  else {
   console.log(row+"row");
  }
 }));   **what it gives me on console is this**   hhhundefined
{ id: 'd62dc582-e4db-40a8-9f96-0cb0203c11a3-00003a56',
  voucher_type: 'Purchase',
  date: '01 Jul 2017',
  amount: 63336,
  voucher_number: '111' }
[object Object]row

Comment: And if you try with my example ?

Comment: i tried your example only..just to differentiate the output on console i added strings

Comment: Yes but it displays you the row, so there is no error ?

Comment: it is not displaying the rows the rows which are shown there are because i had log in getLedgerDetails functions

Comment: from callback function it gives  [object Object]

Comment: It displays you "[object Object]row", so if your console.log(row) instead of console.log(row + "row") ?

Comment: try returning r[0] in the callback

Comment: It displays you the row if you console.log(row) ?

Comment: Can you share what is the response before you parse the data to json object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want your function getLedgerDetails to return data whereas the anonymous function associated with your `connection.query` function is actually returning your data. Being the asynchronous nature of javascript
In your case, you can you can use Promises.

Well, Promises provide us with a cleaner code and handling errors with promises is very easy. Also, promises are better when comes to handling nested callbacks that is one after the another.

For Promise:

```
var Promise = require('promise');


var getLedgerDetails=function(name,id,res) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
         var response=[];
         var f='%d %b %Y';
         connection.query("SELECT id,voucher_type,DATE_FORMAT(date,?) 
              as date,amount,voucher_number FROM sales WHERE 
              ledger_name=? and 
              company_id=? ,[f,name,id],function(err,result){
             if(err){
                reject(err);//or any custom error message.
             }else {
                if(result.length>0){
                    var r=JSON.stringify(result,null,2);
                    var row=JSON.parse(r);
                    resolve(row[0]);
                }else{

                }
            }
      });
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
getLedgerDetails.then(function(success){
   console.log(success)// your db data.
}).catch(function(error) {
    // error handle    
});
```